# Azure app service webjob, how to disable trace logs to application insights

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

I have a .net framework webjob which reads the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY env setting and via the ILogger is sending all debugging statements to application insights as trace logs.

This is getting quite expensive and these logs are not needed.

Is there a way of disabling the trace logs being sent to app insights?

I've tried using appsettings.json, applicationinsights.config but nothing seems to take effect.

Edit: Have also tried adding env settings like `Logging__LogLevel__Default = None` as suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#set-log-level-by-command-line-environment-variables-and-other-configuration but made no difference

Comment: Please post your appsettings.json, applicationinsights.config. What framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using c#, I'm not sure giving any examples of what I have in my config files is any help as nothing I've tried has worked so they're probably just misleading.

Comment: Are you using the .Net framework or .Net or .Net Core?

Comment: We're using .net framework

Answer (score 0):

These logs are coming from ILogger logs. You can use a filter to not collect ILogger logs, so that these logs won't be sent to ApplicationInsights.

[image]

The below code can be used to disable ILogger logs from all category completely.

```cs
builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.None);
```

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
 static async Task Main()
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
                string instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
                {
                    b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
                }

            });
builder.Logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.None); 
           
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorageQueues();
            });
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }

        }
```

**Applications.json:**

you can also configure in application settings as shown below:

```json
"Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None"
      }
```

Comment: I can't easily get the code changed in our setup, trying the applications.json option it doesn't appear to work, is there somewhere special it needs to go?